# Find the mean of columns with matching column names

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, average, mean

I have a dataframe similar to the following but with thousands of rows and columns:

```
x  y  ghb_00hr_rep1  ghb_00hr_rep2    ghb_00hr_rep3   ghl_06hr_rep1  ghl_06hr_rep2
x  y           2           3                 2                1         3
x  y           5           7                 6                2         1
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
 ghb_00hr     hl_06hr
    2.3           2
     6           1.5
```

My goal is to find the average of the matching columns. I have come up with this: `temp = df.groupby(name, axis=1).agg('mean')` But I am not sure how to define 'name' as the matching columns.

My previous strategy was the following:

```
name = pd.Series(['_'.join(i.split('_')[:-1]) 
        for i in df.columns[3:]],
        index = df.columns[3:]
)
temp = df.groupby(name, axis=1).agg('mean')
    avg = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], temp], 
    axis=1
)
```

However the number of 'replicates' ranges from 1-4 so grouping by index location isn't an option.

Not sure if there is a better way to do this or if I am on the right track.

Comment: Are `name, x, y` normal columns in your data? Also what's your expected output?

Comment: name, x, y are columns but I am not trying to perform any operation on them.

I would like my output for the averaged files to look like this:

I will add the desired output to the question since it isn't formatting correctly in a comment and erase the first columns since they are not relevant and I can easily merge those columns with the temporary df I create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to groupby `level=0`:

```
(df.set_index(['name','x','y'])
   .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
   .mean().reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    name  x  y  ghb_00hr  ghl_06hr
0  gene1  x  y  2.333333       2.0
1  gene2  x  y  6.000000       1.5
```

---

**Update**: for the modified question:

```
d = df.filter(like='gh')
# or d = df.iloc[:, 2:]
# depending on your columns of interest

names = d.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0]

d.groupby(names, axis=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
   ghb_00hr  ghl_06hr
0  2.333333       2.0
1  6.000000       1.5
```

Comment: The problem is slightly more complex than I thought since the entire column name is not an exact match. I edited the post accordingly and also listed what I used when I thought that each column had only 3 reps. Is there a solution similar to this method that will work?

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what the `d = df.filter` is doing?

Comment: It's extract all columns containing `gh`. Modify that line as commented to your heart's content.

Comment: Awesome. And the line below using iloc is doing the same thing but by index instead of name?

Comment: Yes, by the numerical index of the columns instead of name.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `df.columns` to set then iterate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'])

for column in set(df.columns):
    print(column, df[common_name].mean(axis=1))
```

will outputs

```
a 0    2.0
dtype: float64
b 0    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Use `sorted` if the order matters:

```
for column in sorted(set(df.columns)):
```

From here you can get the output in pretty much any format you want.